# How to get correct Canon GX6000 driver?

Tags: drivers, printing, pdf, canon

I have the Canon GX6000 printer.

When I try to save a document from browser (Firefox), only Canon_Gx6000_serios is shown. When I try to print, nothing happens:

[image]

When I download the pdf, open it with document viewer, then three drivers are shown, but only the ******.local one is working:

[image]

I keep forgetting this. Is there anything to avoid seeing stale printer drivers?